# Get what's in one array and not the other, in javascript

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have two arrays, `sample1` and `sample2`. How can I get what's in sample1, but not `sample2`?

```
var sample1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var sample2 = [1, 2];

var sample3 = [3, 4]; //what I want to get
```

Application of this: two arrays, each containing some discord.js guildmembers.

**What I've tried:**

```
console.log(sample1.find(el => !sample2.includes(el)).toString());
// Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

I understand a way to do this is to look through the sample1 array, and then if something is not in sample2, push it to a new array. However, I understand there are shorter and more efficient ways of doing this, especially if sample1 and sample2 were quite long.

For clarification, sample1 and sample2 are not undefined.

Comment: First, try logging without the `.toString()` - to try and go back to understnad why what ever you get is `undefined`

Comment: When I try that I just get `undefined` in my console

Comment: What is `guildMember`? String, object or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.find()` Will return the first element that matches the condition.
What you are looking for is getting back a new array. For that you can use `.filter()` which returns a filtered array like so:
`console.log(sample1.filter(el => !sample2.includes(el))); // outputs [3, 4]`